# How to stop turning off sequence when power manager says that battery is too low and want to power down?

Tags: shutdown, battery, gnome-power-manager

According to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6491/laptop-immediately-suspends-when-going-onto-battery-power) I can disable this thing altogether but this battery-critical-power-down not always happens. Is there a way or terminal command that can stop the power manager shutting down my computer when that infamous message box pops up?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Insert `nothing` here and it should just crash with undetermined results if it actually ends up with an empty battery. Run `gconf-editor` from command line and go to `apps` > `gnome-power-management` > `actions`.

Command line option:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/gnome-power-manager/actions/critical_battery       nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the computer can be set to either Shutdown, or Hibernate (free space/swap space providing).

If Hibernation is something you consider an alternative, then you should be able to change it in the Power Manager.

If not, then the system is trying to protect it's hard disks/memory from corruption, and it would be very difficult to disable, and is something i can't help with.

Comment: Are you referring to GNOME 3?

Comment: Not specifically, Unity and Gnome 2 offer the same functionality.