# How to cancel a shutdown process invoked through a low battery state?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop turning off sequence when power manager says that battery is too low and want to power down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31163/how-to-stop-turning-off-sequence-when-power-manager-says-that-battery-is-too-low)

Usually I open a root window to have a chance to stop the invoked shutdown sequence because Ubuntu **must** first ask for permission to close the root window.

BUT several times later I forget that the shutdown sequence was initiated and close the root window. This leads to a shutdown even when the system is already back on the power line and recharging the battery.

`shutdown -c` in a/the still open root window doesn't work here.