# Where do I set use_time_for_policy?

Tags: 11.10, suspend, battery

Where do i find the "use_time_for_policy" fix in ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot?

This post fixed it before.
[Laptop immediately suspends when going onto battery power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6491/laptop-immediately-suspends-when-going-onto-battery-power)

I installed dconf-tools (dconf-editor) but A - didnt find a "search" option like gconf-editor, and B - after looking through them one by one, couldnt even find an entry similar to use_time_for_policy.

Did I just miss it, or is there something else i need to be doing / looking for?

Comment: Now that you know the path it would be great if you were to post an answer on the question you just linked so 11.10 users can find it, thanks!

Comment: you can search trough dconf from command line ;)

Answer (score 7):

Searching `dconf` from command line for `policy` with...

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep policy|more
```

results in 3 lines with 1 of them being...

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true
```

and you can set it from command line with...

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy false
```

Comment: same problem for me on 11.10. This fixed mine,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The path has moved under dconf.  You can find this setting under:

org > gnome > settings-daemon > plug-ins > power

And you are right, there doesn't appear to be any find functionality in dconf-editor.  That's too bad.